# XSLT Tags attributes are getting lost

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-inf metadata-complete="true">
    <A>
       <A1>DGDDG</A1>
       <A1>TYTY</A1>
    </A>
</web-inf>
```

When i am applying my transforms then the O/P XML is just dumping the `<web-inf>` tag without the metadata-complete="true" i.e as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-inf>
    <A>
       <A1>DGDDG</A1>
       <A1>TYTY</A1>
    </A>
</web-inf>
```

My XSLT Transform file has below in the beginning.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="web-inf[not(A/A1='hello')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="XXX"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not sure what going wrong here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code written inside template `XXX` which is being called from the XSLT?

Comment: Yes. Here is the code within XXX

`<xsl:template name="XXX">
        <M>
            <N-name>1</N-name>
            <N-value>2</N-value>
        </M>
         <M>
            <N-name>3</N-name>
            <N-value>4</N-value>
        </M>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: @TestUser - please don't use comments for additional information that belongs in the question.  Edit the question to include the information.

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:copy>` copies only the current node, but not any attributes or child nodes. You are already catering for the child nodes with `<xsl:apply-templates />` (which is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`), but you also need to handle selecting attributes separately.

```
<xsl:template match="web-inf[not(A/A1='hello')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:call-template name="XXX"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```